# Javascript - Remove elements from an array / sum elements in an array above a certain value

Tags: javascript, arrays

(1)

I have here an array that is a mix of strings and ints:

```
var newArr = [ 22, 7, "2761", 16, "91981", "37728", "13909", "247214", "8804", 6, 2 ]
```

My ultimate goal is to remove the values that are ints, and add the other values.

One way I tried to achieve this was to first convert all to ints:

```
  for (element in newArr) {
    newArr[element] = parseInt(newArr[element], 10);
  }
```

Is this the best way to do that?
It seems to output an array of ints like this:

```
var newArr = [ 22, 7, 2761, 16, 91981, 37728, 13909, 247214, 8804, 6, 2 ];
```

(2)

Then I would like to only sum elements in newArr that are above the value of 30.
This is my code:

```
var newArr = [ 22, 7, 2761, 16, 91981, 37728, 13909, 247214, 8804, 6, 2 ];

  for (element in newArr) {
    if (newArr[element] > 30) {
      sum += newArr[element];
    }
  }
```

It doesn't seem to be working. Please help.

(3)
A final question is:

How could I just eliminate the ints from newArr in step (1), as this would negate the need for the other code, I guess.

A simple solution using only javascript syntax (no jquery) would be appreciated.
(unless the overwhelming consensus is that jquery would be a better option)
Thanks Javascript Ninjas!

Comment: This seems overly-complicated, what are you actually trying to achieve? Because, in all honesty, I'd be surprised if this *isn't* an "[XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)."

Comment: You want to read about the Array methods .reduce(), .includes(), .map() as well as Javascript's typeof. It shouldn't take you more than a few minutes to figure out, good luck !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you might want to look into [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). This will allow you to convert them all to ints.

```
var result = newArr.map(function(x) {
  return parseInt(x, 10);
});
```

Then you can use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove any elements less than or equal to 30.

```
result = result.filter(function(x) {
  return x > 30;
});
```

Finally, you can use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to sum them all together.

```
sum = result.reduce(function(sum, x) {
  return sum + x;
}, 0);
```

There are numerous ways of accomplishing this but I like this approach because you can chain it together.

```
var sum = newArray.map(function(x) {
      return parseInt(x, 10);
    })
    .filter(function(x) {
      return x > 30;
    })
    .reduce(function(sum, x) {
      return sum + x;
    }, 0);
```

Comment: `var res = newArr.map(Number).reduce(function(s, n) { return n > 30 ? n+s : s; }, 0);`

Comment: @LyeFish I like that. The only problem is that it won't guarantee parsing numbers in base 10. Example: `new Number('0x88') == 136`

Comment: Very good point assuming they don't want hexadecimal evaluation. Another approach would be `var res = newArr.map(parseFloat)...`. This'll handle decimals too. Only problem would be if the string `"Infinity"` exists in the list, which `parseFloat` will parse to `Infinity`.

Answer (score 0):

Detect the type then remove them:  Here I go through the array, then remove the numbers then go through it again:

```
var newArr = [22, 7, "2761", 16, "91981", "37728", "13909", "247214", "8804", 6, 2];

for (element in newArr) {
    alert(typeof newArr[element] + ":" + newArr[element]);
}
for (var i = newArr.length; i--;) {
    if (typeof newArr[i] === "number") {
        newArr.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
alert(newArr.length);
for (element in newArr) {
    alert(typeof newArr[element] + ":" + newArr[element]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mark, for this alternative.

Comment: Note I went through the array backwards to avoid issues with the changing length.  And in older browsers it is faster to traverse the array this way.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach to do all this in single iteration would be .

1. Checking each element with typeof item!="number"
2. Using Array's Reduce Right :
   Sample Use:

   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4].reduceRight(function(previousValue, currentValue, index, array) {
      return previousValue + currentValue;
   });

You can check the previousValue and currentValue with typeof and return the addition if parseInt() return's 30 or more.